# Testing fetch request with jest does not work

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch

I have fetch request as follows:

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';
import { contentFetchCompleted, contentFetchError, contentFetchStarted } from './actions';

export const CONTENT_QUERY = `query SalesContent ($key: String!) {
  salesContent (key: $key) {
       data
  }
}`;

export const contentFetch = (key, context) => (dispatch, state) => {
  if (state.content[key] && !state.content[key].fetching && state.content[key].language !== context.culture) {
    dispatch(contentFetchStarted(key, context.culture));

    fetch("/graphql", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": context.culture
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: CONTENT_QUERY, variables: { key: key } })
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch(contentFetchCompleted(key, context.culture, result.data.salesContent.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(contentFetchError(key, context.culture, err));
      });
  }
};
```

And I try to test it with jest. The tests are as follows:

```
const mockFetch = request => {
  global.fetch = request
}

const contextMock = { culture: 'nl' };
const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
const stateMock = {
  content: {
    [key]: {
      fetching: false,
      language: 'fr',
    },
  },
};

beforeAll(() => {
  mockFetch()
})

describe("FETCH CONTENT", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear the mock calls before each test
    dispatchMock.mockClear();
  });

  test('should dispatch contentFetchStarted action if conditions are met', () => {
    mockFetch(mockedFetchContentSuccess)
    // Call the contentFetch function
    contentFetch(key, contextMock)(dispatchMock, stateMock);

    // Verify that the dispatch function is called with the expected action
    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(contentFetchStarted(key, contextMock.culture));
  });

  test('should fetch data and dispatch contentFetchCompleted action', async () => {
    // Mock the fetch function to return a response
    mockFetch(mockedFetchContentSuccess)

    // Call the contentFetch function
    await contentFetch(key, contextMock)(dispatchMock, stateMock);

    // Verify that the dispatch function is called with the expected action
    await expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(contentFetchCompleted(key, contextMock.culture, data))
  });
})
```

First test is fine. But for the second test i get an error:

```
FETCH CONTENT › should fetch data and dispatch contentFetchCompleted action

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
        "payload": Object {
    -     "data": "Some dummy data",
          "key": "financing",
          "language": "nl",
        },
    -   "type": "CONTENT_FETCH_COMPLETED",
    +   "type": "CONTENT_FETCH_STARTED",
      },

    Number of calls: 1

      45 |
      46 |     // Verify that the dispatch function is called with the expected action
    > 47 |     await expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(contentFetchCompleted(key, contextMock.culture, data))
         |                                ^
      48 |   });
      49 | })
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

`mockedFetchContentSuccess` is as follows:

```
export const mockedFetchContentSuccess = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      json: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
          data: {
            salesContent: {
              data: data
            },
          },
        }),
    })
  }

);
```

Comment: Jest `expect` is not asynchronous and adding `await` in front of it has no effect.  Try `await waitFor(() => expect(....`

Comment: It's hard to tell what is supposed to happen because you haven't posted what `mockedFetchContentSuccess` is.

Comment: You're also heavily relying on `cross-fetch` to be calling the global `fetch`.  I'd mock the `cross-fetch` function over global fetch since you don't own it.